# How to make animation start on button hover

Tags: html, onhover

```
<div id="troll">Info</div>
<a href=xyz1.php">XYZ1</a>
<a href=xyz2.php">XYZ2</a>
<a href=xyz3.php">XYZ3</a>
<a href=xyz4.php">XYZ4</a>
```

I want to do such thing, that if I hover mouse on XYZ1, info for XYZ1 will show up in div#troll, for XYZ2, XYZ2 etc. but when user unhovers a=href, I want div to be invisible. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for you situation I would use Javascript to do this as your constraint is getting the data into that one div.

First I would try something like:

**HTML**

```
<div id="troll">Info</div>
<a class="infoLink" href="xyz1.php" data-info="Info On XYZ1">XYZ1</a>
<a class="infoLink" href="xyz2.php" data-info="Info On XYZ2">XYZ2</a>
<a class="infoLink" href="xyz3.php" data-info="Info On XYZ3">XYZ3</a>
<a class="infoLink" href="xyz4.php" data-info="Info On XYZ4">XYZ4</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.infoLink').hover(
  function()
  {
      $('#troll').html($(this).attr('data-info'));
  },
  function()
  {
      $('#troll').empty();
  }
);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puY3M/)

[jQuery Hover Doc](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

I am just using the attribute "data-info" to pull text out of the anchor and add it to the div you specified. There are many different ways this could be achieved though.

**EDIT**

This solution does require [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to work. It is possible with pure Javascript however jQuery makes your code a lot smaller and easier to implement.

Comment: It seems a little odd that a client-side Javascript change would be affected by XAMPP, a PHP/Apache server. If you get any more details as to why though, I might be able to look into it further.

Comment: I am not sure if it's XAMPP, it simply doesn't work on my PC.

Comment: Is it happening in a particular browser you are using? One thought came to mind that I didn't directly mention in my answer (which I will update) but it does require [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to work. It looks like any jQuery version will do as `.hover` has been in jQuery since version 1.0

Comment: Greatest excuses. I included jquery with .js, but the real file I need to use is .min.js (the one I downloaded at least). Thank you. I've tested it, and it works.

Comment: No problem, just make sure to make the answer as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with Javascript. If you are going to use a Library you can use jQuery. An example can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

```
$("a").hover(function(){
    $("#troll").fadeIn();
}, function(){
    $("#troll").fadeOut();
})
```

Comment: That's not actually what I am looking for. If I hover "Chips" or "Socks" in your demo, they disappear, and they come back. I need to external element to be effected.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I was on wrong demo section. That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much.